# Can't save theme options, following a tutorial from tutsplus

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

I know that the question has been asked before, why isn't my code saving, but this tutorial was recently recommended by a user here, and I have been following it from tuts plus, (obviously changing variables and options to fit my needs), but for some reason the little bar that says settings saved will come up, and the save button comes up, the form itself, it all looks right, but when I hit save, it is gone from the form. Keep in mind that I have only tried saving the settings for the first options, site logo url. Here is my code, it is properly included in the functions.php file.

PS: Sorry for it all being together, PHP and HTML, but that was the only way to get it all together in one post, plus, I like to put things in separate files after I finish.

```
<?php
 if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    wp_die('You do not have permission to view this page, if you believe that this is a mistake, please contact your system administrator, or try closing the tab and come back.');
}


 add_action("admin_menu", "setup_where_now_admin_menus");

 function setup_where_now_admin_menus() {
    add_menu_page('Front Door Theme Options', 'Front Door Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'where_now_elements', 'where_now_options') ;
}
?>

<?php
function where_now_options() { ?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Front Door Web Design Custom Theme Options</h2>
<form method="post" action="">


<h4>Site Logo URL</h4>
<p>Remember, this is the image used in places like your header, or anywhere else you want your logo to appear, and if you are having trouble remembering how to use this feature, you can always upload your new logo to the media section in Wordpress, get the URL from the specific images page, and then paste it here!</p>     
<input type="text" name="site_logo" value="<?php echo $site_logo;?>" size="25">


    <h4>Analytics Tracking Code</h4>
    <p>Any code used for tracking purposes that is placed in the header goes here</p>
    <input type="text" name="analytics_code">


    <?php
    $site_logo = get_option("where_now_site_logo");

    if (isset($_POST["update_settings"])) {

    $site_logo = esc_attr($_POST["site_logo"]); 
update_option("where_now_site_logo", $site_logo);
?>
<div id="message" class="updated">Your Changes Have Been Saved</div>
<?php

}
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="update_settings" value="Y" />

    <input type="submit" value="Save settings" class="button-primary"/>
</form>
</div>
<?php    
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this Plugin: [Option Tree](http://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/)
It is very simple and doesn't need any coding.Just install it on your website that your theme is running,then you can manage your options easily.

Comment: I'll look into that, but I am making a base theme for making client sites. I would rather just code it.

Comment: I think this may help you [Options Framework](http://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/)